# How to "pretty print" an XML string in C++ without ANY other modifications?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, boost, xml-parsing

How to "pretty print" an XML string in C++ using Qt or boost?

I have an input like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Something property1="A" property2="B"><Value>42</Value></Something>
```

an I want to receive this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Something property1="A" property2="B">
        <Value>42</Value>
    </Something>
```

Sounds like a very simple task, but I have difficulties with solving it properly using Qt or boost.

When I try to use a `QDomDocument`

```
QDomDocument dom_document;
dom_document.setContent(unformatted_xml);
QString formatted_xml = dom_document.toString(4);
```

it both messes with the quotes (https://forum.qt.io/topic/68098/issue-with-qdomdocument-setcontent-and-xml-declaration-attribute-quotes) and swaps some properties (e.g., `property2` might end up being *before* `property1`)

When I try to use a `boost::property_tree`

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree pt;

std::istringstream iss{i_unformatted_xml};
read_xml(iss, pt, (boost::property_tree::xml_parser::trim_whitespace | boost::property_tree::xml_parser::no_concat_text));

boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<std::string> settings{' ', 4};
std::ostringstream result_oss;
write_xml(result_oss, pt, settings);
```

it messes with the header, removing its `standalone` property completely and transforming `"UTF-8"` to lowercase.

Is there a way to **just** format an XML string without modifying **any** non-whitespace characters in it?
E.g., like the XML Tools plugin for Notepad++ does.

Comment: Are you open to other libraries, or you're restricted to either QT or Boost?

Comment: @parktomatomi  If there is no good solution in Qt nor Boost, then I might try other libraries.

Comment: You got the original xml, You need to verify checksum, but checksum will not be correct after formatting, your question devoid of logic.

Comment: @Deep What? Your answer is devoid of logic, imagining some checksums I never mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [QXmlFormatter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlformatter.html), another way of formatting XML in Qt. At least from the documentation its purpose seems to be to just insert linebreaks and space characters, not modifying the XML in other ways. (I didn't verify in a test, though.)

QXmlFormatter works on QXmlQuery output, so you'd have to use a fake XQuery that does not change its input.